# Deletion in sparse index

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a sparse index in PostgreSQl like:

```
Index   Data Block
A ----> A
...     B
        C
        ...
```

`A,B and C` are in the same data block. Now if I delete A, what exactly happens? I mean I know that my index will now hold `B` instead of `A`, but will it look like:

```
Index   Data Block
B ----> B
...     C
        ...
```

or

```
Index   Data Block
B ----> -
...     B
        C
        ...
```

where by `-` I mean that its left blank.

Thanks!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and the implementation of an index structure is completely vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not using any specific language. I was reading some slides on "Deletion in sparse indexes" and had this doubt

Comment: As I said: every DBMS product implements indexes in a different way. Without the concrete implementation this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "implementation of an index structure is completely vendor specific" --- does it mean that both implementations are correct and may be used?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How about postgres?

Comment: I don't know how that "sparse index" is defined, but PostgreSQL doesn't have such a data structure.